# Can i use control, shift or other special key combinations as password when login in linux?

Tags: linux, security, bash

When i was a undergraduate, my c++ teacher says he use special keys combinations as passowrd(cool, right?). I did not think about it too much at that time. Today I googled, but did not find a good result. What do you think about it?

Comment: This question would be much happier on unix.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a good idea. It's harder to recognize, for someone which is looking to your keyboard, while you typing in your password.

I've tried it under Debian and it was no problem. For example we want a user with the password  `End Of Text` or in other words <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

I did this with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is for escaping.